# CSS Menu with border-radius on hover

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu

Maybe it is a simple solution, but I stuck to it.

Here I have my code http://jsbin.com/ejomuv pure CSS menu

What I want to do, is to set on Dropdown button bottom 0px border-radius on hover, but only on dropdown menus not on all.

I tried, but it isn't working, I know that I don't do something right:

```
#nav li a .nav-dropdown:hover {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px; 
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since anchor tags with dropdown menus are using `action` instead of `href`, you could use the following selector:

```
#nav > li:hover > a[action]{
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px; 
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;  
}
```

**Working example: http://jsbin.com/ejomuv/7/**

Comment: Is working, but, I made the background black, as you are able to see a detail http://jsbin.com/ejomuv/5/edit#preview , in that way, the button is always with no radius on bottom

Comment: @DenisHoss Sorry, I missed out the `:hover`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Yes I saw, no problems, and everything is ok, but now when you hover a sumbenu, the button radius is screwed up. Look http://jsbin.com/ejomuv/9/edit

Comment: @DenisHoss - I think you are one update behind ;) (the `:hover` needs to be on the `li`)

Answer (score 2):

If the reference is correct (which I cannot tell because the HTML is missing) it should work fine. But I think that's exactly the problem. Maybe try to add an !important flag in your statement to see if that helps.

Comment: HTML isn't missing, click please the edit button on the right, to see the source code :) http://jsbin.com/ejomuv/edit#html

Comment: Srry...I didn't notice the jsbin link ;)

Answer (score 2):

You may target the element using the `>` ([Child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors)).

```
#nav > li:hover > a {
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
}
```

This will go specifically from the `#nav` to the child `li` when on over, to the child `a`.